# XML File without root node in ant

Tags: ant, xml-parsing

Is reading an xml file without root node in ant possible?
for examples file like

```
<house>
   <name>a</name>
</house>
<house>
   <name>b</name>
</house>
<house>
   <name>c</name>
</house>
```

is it possible to traverse the names in this file in ant?

Answer (score 0):

Ant does use standard Java XML parsers, which expects XML is well formed, so have one root element. See https://coderwall.com/p/3ddyka/how-to-parse-a-file-xml-without-root-or-a-malformed-xml-in-java how to add root element from Java code.

Comment: I was actually trying to do the same in ant but so far haven't succeeded. 
Thank you for the help.